# Adding UITableView backgroundView with UIView with UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uibutton

I am trying to set my `UITableView` backgroundView to `UIView` and inside the `UIView` I added a `UIButton` but the `UIButton` is not appearing. What am I doing wrong?

```
let view: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.menuTable.bounds.size.width, height: self.menuTable.bounds.size.height))

let loginButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
loginButton.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
loginButton.tintColor = UIColor.black
loginButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.pressedConnection), for: .touchUpInside)
view.addSubview(loginButton)

self.menuTable.backgroundView = view
self.menuTable.separatorStyle = .none
```

Comment: Why are you adding a button to the view that is shown behind a table view's cells?

Comment: When are you showing that view as background View ? do tableView have any data at that time ?